# Finite extension of decidable theory is decidable

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Exactly what it says on the tin. I'm trying to prove that if T2 is a finite extension of decidable theory T1, then T2 is decidable.

Comment: When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include any work you have done on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 2):

We may assume that $T_2$ is $T_1$ together with a single additional axiom $\alpha$. For any sentence $\varphi$, we have that $\varphi$ is a theorem of $T_2$ if and only if $\alpha\to\varphi$ is a theorem of $T_1$.

By assumption, there is an algorithm that will, on input $\psi$, decide whether or not $\psi$ is a theorem of $T_1$. To determine whether or not $\varphi$ is a theorem of $T_2$, apply that algorithm to $\alpha\to\varphi$.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I've got it now.

Comment: You are welcome.